# Google app engine stuck deploying with appcfg

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-launch

Google app engine refuses to deploy my latest build, and looking at the releases list, I can see that another build has been 'deploying' for the better part of a week.

Google doesn't offer support anymore for this without paying for it, but this is stuff that just shouldn't happen.
Hope one of you google engineers out there can help me with this. The google project is caleld vxlpay.

[image: Image showing deploying for days]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing an appcfg rollback?

Comment: Hi, havent tried it. I found another way of fixing the problem starting to deploy using GAE launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Please cancel the deployment if it gets stuck; just waiting for it to finish often leads to frustration and desk-flipping. There's a few ways to help you deploy the app.

1) Generally, you can simply redeploy after waiting a few minutes.
2) Redeploy with another deployment method (appcfg, Google App Launcher, Eclipse...)
3) Rollback then redeploy

If all 3 fails, there might be something wrong with your configuration and you would probably need to speak to the support engineers at Google.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it's not possible. Getting in touch with support engineers on google took me one week. I am not sure what happened, only saw that all my releases were deleted. Finally got this up and running again by turning off the github autodeploy, and deploying from localhost using the GAE toolkit. Not satisfied with Google. Either you are running a fully managed service, or your are not.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into to this just now.
<s>I think my issue had something to do with having a browser open to the site I was trying to deploy to. Apparently that was locking up a process or something because, when I closed it, my deploy finished.</s>

Silly, yes. I think it has something to do with GAE attempting to migrate traffic but not dealing with cases where there's browsers open... There's probably a feature that allows for deploying and controlling whether or not traffic is migrated.

I'll have to give that a try to see if closing the connection (browser) resolved it or if it was just a timing thing.

Nope... Just takes an absurdly long time.

Maybe it's due to file sizes?

Note: This only occurs when deploying a Flex environment rather a standard one.